# Perturbative renormalization as re-parametrization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory

I've read that the source of UV divergences in perturbative renormalization is due to a bad choice of parametrization. But since we have some freedom over how to reparametrize, and some of them are "bad" choices, where "good" ones lead to convergent series and bad ones divergent ones, what distinguishes these options from one another, and what justifies our choice in a particular one?

Comment: The series in QFT never converges as far as I know, renormalization just "pushes away" the divergence. To get a better feel for renormalization I enjoyed reading https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/ms/ren.pdf

Comment: I know that at least in the interesting cases, the series actually doesn't converge/needs to be truncated to give physically sensible results. But then my question still remains: why are some choices of reparametrization good and others bad?